# How to allow only one session per user

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I have been assigned with a task to restrict multiple simultaneous usages of a silverlight application for a single user. Ideally each time user opens new application, previous instance should receive some sort of notification and shut down.

Silverlight application consumes data using WCF services exposed via REST endpoint.
Currently every call to the service has username and password as parameters. This was good because we were having stateless services. There are some apps which use these services already, and I am looking for the least painful solution.

Thanks

Comment: "having stateless services" would seem to be at odds with knowing how many sessions a user has.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I rushed in to answer because I misunderstood the question. I initially thought you were referring to instances on the same computer.

**For preventing multiple instances on the same computer** you can use the [LocalMessageReceiver Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833063%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

You can see a code example [here](http://tozon.info/blog/post/2009/11/01/Detecting-duplicate-instances-of-a-running-Silverlight-application.aspx) that shows you how to prevent the user from opening a second instance of the application. Each LocalMessageReceiver must have a unique channel name as a constructor parameter. If the constructor throws an exception you can assume that there is another instance of the application.

If you want to keep only the last application instance and close the previous ones, then you should create unique channel names for each instance and then dispatch a message to tell the other instances to close.

**For preventing multiple instances of the application on different computers** I'm less qualified to answer, but the first thing that comes to mind is writing in the database whenever a user logs in..

If your services don't necessarily have to remain stateless then you can keep in a database table a unique identifier for each time a user logs in (ex: the login date?), and then whenever the user wants to do some action, you can check if the last identifier from the database corresponds to the one you have in the current session. If not, it means someone logged in with the same user from another computer, so you can expire the session.

Comment: What if a new session is started on different computer?

Comment: hmm.. you are right, thanks. I'll think about it and update the answer

Comment: Thanks @sssilviu, I am not forcing into keeping those services stateless. I can also add a new service just for sl client, or adjust the hosting app somehow to shutdown multiple clients. 

Any ideas could be usefull. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @v00d00, I updated my answer, taking into consideration that you don't need the services to be stateless.

Answer (score 1):

Because Silverlight itself is not a stateless application, you should be able to implement this with a simple service and [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). If you have the usernames and/or guids in your database already, it should be a simple addition to have a singular table keyed of the user's guid that contains some timestamp information and a specific HMAC for a particular login. This HMAC would be generated from something specific about the machine in conjunction with the timestamp it was being generated. Something like:

```
userGuid | activeHMAC | lastLoginDate | currentlyLoggedIn (bit)
```

Then on the login action of the silverlight control, a record for the userGuid can be added or updated to include the current information. This would force all new logins to overwrite existing login HMACs. Then on a logout or close event, simply call the service and set the `currentlyLoggedIn` bit to false.

You would then need to ensure that this HMAC was sent with all communication to a web service so that it could be verified against new calls or have each client periodically call the service to compare the HMAC and disable the client if it fails the comparison. Since Silverlight runs in a disconnected fashion, your choice would probably be governed by data integrity. Personally, I think it would be safer to embed the HMAC into all communications to prevent any kind of lag time from allowing inappropriate actions.